How to verify that an xpath pattern is NOT matched in Wiremock?
I am working on a test case that asserts that the xml request body to a Wiremock stub does not have the xmlns attribute.
So far, I have tried to use the equalToXml matcher, but that is ignoring attributes as far as I can tell.
String customerXml = "<customer xmlns=\"http://example.com\"><name>Jon Doe</name><age>39</age></customer>";
WireMock.stubFor(
    WireMock.get(urlEqualTo("/someservice/customers/123"))
        .willReturn(
            WireMock.aResponse()
                .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .withBody(customerXml)));
Customer customer = customersService.getCustomer(123);

WireMock.stubFor(
    WireMock.post(urlEqualTo(
        "/otherservice/customers/123"))
        .willReturn(
            WireMock.aResponse()
                .withStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED.value())));

Customer customerInSecondSystem = customersService.createCustomer(customer);

String expectedRequestBody = "<customer><name>Jon Doe</name><age>39</age></customer>";
verify(WireMock.postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/otherservice/customers/123"))
    .withRequestBody(equalToXml(expectedRequestBody))); // this will pass even though
                                                        // the xmlns attribute is present in the xml

I then tried to come up with an XPath expression that I could use:
String expectedRequestBody = "<customer><name>Jon Doe</name><age>39</age></customer>";
verify(WireMock.postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/otherservice/customers/123"))
    .withRequestBody(equalToXml(expectedRequestBody))
    .withRequestBody(matchingXPath("*[@xmlns='http://example.com']")));

This will positively match the xmlns attribute in the xml.
Now, how do I have to formulate the XPath to negatively match the xmlns attribute (to make sure it's not present)?

Although namespace declarations have the syntactic form of attributes, they are not considered attributes in the XPath 1.0 data model. So actually for the following XML document,
<customer xmlns="http://example.com"/>

... the following XPath expression should return nothing:
/*/@xmlns

Instead, namespace declarations appear in XPath's data model as "namespace nodes". Each namespace node has a prefix (which can be blank) and a URI.
For background, I'd strongly recommend reading the W3C document "Namespaces in XML 1.0" which explains the purpose of namespaces and how they work.
If a namespace declaration has the form xmlns="http://example.com/", then this sets a so-called "default namespace", whose namespace prefix is blank. If the declaration has the form xmlns:foo="http://example.com/", then the namespace prefix is "foo", but in both cases the namespace URI (which is really the significant part of the declaration) is http://example.com/.
For a given element, you can access its namespace URI using the namespace-uri() function; its name without a prefix using the local-name() function, and its name including any prefix using the name() function.
NB in the two documents below, the names of the root elements are considered to be the same (!). The name of an XML element is a pair of two values: the "local" part (customer in both cases), and the namespace URI (http://example.com/ in both cases). The namespace prefixes ("foo", and "", respectively) are not significant.
<foo:customer xmlns:foo="http://example.com/"/>

<customer xmlns="http://example.com/"/>

You can access namespace nodes in XPath using the namespace axis. e.g. the following expression will return the namespace nodes in scope on the root customer element:
/customer/namespace::node()

You can use the local-name() function on a namespace node to read its prefix, and the string() function to read its namespace URI.
It's not clear from your question what constraint you really intend to impose. On the face of it, it sounds like you want to check that there's no declaration of the default namespace on the root element, but my guess is that what you probably want is to check that the root element's namespace URI is blank (i.e. that the root element's name does not belong to a namespace):
namespace-uri(/*) = ''

If in fact you really do want to check that the root element has no "default" namespace declared, then you could use this boolean XPath expression:
not(/*/namespace::node()[local-name(.)=''])

(Meaning "the root element does not have a namespace node whose namespace prefix is blank").
But NB that expression would return true for the following document:
<foo:customer xmlns:foo="http://example.com/"/>

... because the http://example.com/ namespace node has a non-blank prefix: foo.
